# How to convert DB2 timestamp to datetime?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I convert a timestamp returned from DB2 ISeries to DateTime datatype in c#?

```
2012-07-06 09:52:50.926145
```

This did not worked for me

```
myEmployee.LastModified = Convert.ToDateTime(myRecord.GetString(myRecord.GetOrdinal("LASTMODIFIED")));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`DateTime.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx)?

```
DateTime result = DateTime.Parse("2012-07-06 09:52:50.926145");
```

[It works, really.](http://ideone.com/39IA8)

Comment: Thanks for your reply miniTech. It seems GetString inside C# is the problem. It is returning me 2012-07-06-09:52:50.926145 for some odd reason.Notice the extra '-'

Comment: @DamienJoe: Then use `DateTime.ParseExact("2012-07-06-09:52:50.926145", "yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm:ss.FFFFFF", null)`. [Here's a demo.](http://ideone.com/AExyK)

Comment: Excellent workaround ! Thumbs up for all the help =) Do you know why GetString is doing this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `DateTime.TryParse()`

```
DateTime date;
DateTime.TryParse("2012-07-06 09:52:50.926145", out date);
```

In your case

```
DateTime date,
DateTime.TryParse(myRecord.GetString(myRecord.GetOrdinal("LASTMODIFIED")), out date);
```

Comment: Thanks @Asif GetString returns 2012-07-06-09:52:50.926145 however it seems to be fine in query manager.

Comment: You can replace it with a white space by int index = "2012-07-06-09:52:50.926145".LastIndex("-");